# Adding CefSharp dependencies to application files

Tags: c#, clickonce

I have several files that I need to add to my projects application files. These are the dependencies for CefSharp but are required when publishing my application. Would anyone be able to give me any guidance into how I would go about doing this? I have provided a snippet below of all the files which are required and the place where I am looking to place them. Thanks in advance.

[image]
[image]

Comment: This a a ClickOnce deployment?

Comment: Yes, it is. :).

Comment: I ran in to a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52819190/deploy-exe-provided-by-nuget-package-as-a-component-of-a-clickonce-installation) issue with Click-Once, but unfortunately, never found a satisfactory solution.

Comment: I don't know whether you are still dealing with this issue but I solved mine from this source > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34225222/clickonceinstall-cefsharp-winforms-problems

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34225222/clickonceinstall-cefsharp-winforms-problems